# Force-unwrapping dispose bag while using RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I want to use RxSwift but alwo don't want to force-unwrap.

When I use [weak self] I get the error that self must be unwrapped - ie. self can't be optional in this case

```
public func getPages() -> Observable<[(String, String)]> {
    return Observable.create {
        [weak self] observer -> Disposable in
        if let pages = self?.pages {
            observer.onNext(pages)
        } else {
            self?.allPages()
                .debug()
                .subscribe({ event in
                    switch event {
                    case .next(let dta):
                        observer.onNext(dta)
                    case .error(let error):
                        observer.onError(error)
                    case .completed:
                        break
                    }
                }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

my solution has been to force-unwrap self at that point, however this is not right.

i.e.

```
}).disposed(by: self!.disposeBag)
```

So how can I avoid force-unwrapping in this case?

Comment: Why can't you use a `guard` statement to bail early, if `self` has been deinitialized?

Comment: I can, but then I'm returning a Publish subject that I *think* is empty, would be good to know if there is a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code presented is all kinds of wrong... If I understand what you are trying to do, a simple share is all you need:

```
let getPages = allPages()
    .share(replay: 1)
```

Once you subscribed to `getPages`, the share operator will cache the emission and replay it to every other observer that subscribes to it.

Otherwise, notice that you are supposed to return a disposable from the create closure. You are generating a disposable when you call subscribe and then putting one in the dispose bag instead of returning it. Instead, do something like this:

```
func getPages() -> Observable<[(String, String)]> {
    return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
        guard let this = self else {
            observer.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
        guard let pages = this.pages else {
            return this.allPages()
                .subscribe(observer)
        }
        observer.onNext(pages)
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

- If self doesn't exist by the time the observable is subscribed to, then just complete.
- If self exists, but pages doesn't, then call allPages() and bind it to the observer.
- Otherwise, emit pages and complete.

Comment: You're not being arrogant, because at least you couch your attack on the code with the initial volley "The code presented is all kinds of wrong... If I understand what you are trying to do...". Thanks for the tips, delivered without grace.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a 'unowned' instead of 'weak' reference. The difference between them is that unowned presumes that the self is not null. Replacing [weak self] by [unowned self] makes self not to be optional, so you don't need to unwrap it.

Answer (score -1):

It happens because you haven't defined weak self in second completion.

Please see below code in that case self will become optional.

.subscribe({  [weak self] event in

Comment: You have to return a value! As this discussion above, I've used publish subject. Plus if you do this self becomes optional!

Comment: Okay I understand your concern.  How you don't need force-unwrap self.disposeBag you avoid that right, Because there is another completions so there you didn't defined  [weak self] that's why it works.

Comment: Add below code you will get that self also optional.
.subscribe({ [weak self] event in